Is there a way to tell latexmk ab out makefiles it needs for the compilation?
Is there a way to add make dependencies to latexmk? What I want is to simply write in the latexmkrc something like
$make_deps = "path to makefile"

So that the all target is added as a dependency for the compilation of the latex document. That is, whenever something changes, latexmk will invoke make on the required makefiles and update the targets and then compile the latex document.

It's not possible to give a general answer without know more about the kinds of dependencies involved, and the reasons for wanting to use make rather than a suitable configuration for latexmk.  A user encountering this kind of situation should examine the latexmk documentation, and especially the sections on "Custom Dependencies" and "Advanced configuration: Using latexmk with make".

For many simple dependencies, e.g., making a pdf file from a file generated by a graphics editor, a custom dependency is the best solution, since it is integrated with latexmk's analysis of dependencies. The section includes an example.

Within latexmk, there are solutions for more complicated cases.  For ideas, see for example the files in the example_rcfiles directory in the latexmk distribution

When make is really needed, exactly what to do depends on the situation. The section "Advanced configuration: Using latexmk with make" in the latexmk documentation shows how to go about configuring latexmk to invoke make when needed.


